# Replicating Back Button Function at Top of Hierarchy

Tags: android

I have overridden my back button method and I want to know, when at the top of the hierarchy how to put my application in the background and return it the android home screen. So replicating its usual function when there is no more to go back to?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you already did..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but to simply make your App do, what the system would do when the user presses the back button, use *super.onBackPressed();*

I hope this helps.